# Faddeev-Popov Haar measure invariance for $U(1)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, path-integral, gauge-invariance

I am studying the Faddeev-Popov procedure for quantizing Gauge fields. I am stuck in the step where it says that the measure is gauge invariant for the $U(1)$ case.

I came across this question on stackexchange: [How to apply the Faddeev-Popov method to a simple integral](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221848/)

Here OP says in the question that ${\cal D}\omega\omega' = {\cal D}\omega$, for fixed $\omega'$, which follows from the product rule, but I don't see how. I figured:

$D\omega\omega' = \omega'{\cal D}\omega + \omega {\cal D}\omega'$, where the second term goes to zero as $\omega'$ is just a fixed gauge transformation. But then ${\cal D}\omega\omega' = \omega'{\cal D}\omega$.

So, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

${\cal D}$ is *not* a differentiation; ${\cal D}\omega=\prod_x d\omega(x)$  is a path integral measure, and the right invariance of the [Haar measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) is being used.

Comment: I get that it is not a differentiation, but still how can the invariance be shown explicitly? A derivation would be really helpful.

Comment: You mean an explicit formula for the Haar measure for the $SU(N)$ group?

Comment: Not just the formula. A proof that it really is invariant under a fixed U(1) transformation.

Comment: Well, the path integral measure is not a well-defined mathematical object. The proof is only formal.

Comment: There obviously  has to be some sort of proof! The entire Faddeev-Popov method stands on this very fact. Introduction to Gauge Field Theory by Bailin & Love page 120 for reference.

Comment: The formal proof typically discretizes spacetime. Within each lattice site $x$, the gauge transformation  $\omega^{\prime}$ is given by a group element $\omega^{\prime}(x)$. Next apply right invariance property of the Haar measure wrt. that group element. End formal proof.

Comment: @Qmechanic I believe OP is asking for the proof of invariance of $d\omega(x)$. It is indeed trivial: the Haar measure is invariant by construction (an explicit formula for the measure on $SU(n)$ in group coordinates would be nice, but I am too lazy to look it up). Anyways, for $U(1)$ the measure is $d\omega = d\varphi / (2\pi)$ with $\varphi \in [0..2\pi)$. On the other hand, $\mathcal{D} \omega$ is invariant under the $SU(n)$ **gauge** group (which is a product of $SU(n)$ at all points of spacetime). This is of course highly formal and is far from being well-defined, as you've mentioned.

Comment: @Solenodon Paradoxus: Agree. That is what I was trying to say in my previous comment.